# Transfer Control Of @skepticexchange Twitter account

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Now all the network sites are getting there own dedicated twitter feeds I was wonder if StackExchange would like to take control of the [@skepticexchange](http://twitter.com/skepticexchange) account I set up when I created Skeptics.SE v1.

It has 500+ followers, but has been neglected in recent months.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is already an official Twitter account: https://twitter.com/StackSkeptic

Ideas on how to merge!?

Comment: I suggest posting a final tweet from @skepticexchange pointing to `@stackskeptic` -- something like "this twitter account is defunct -- please follow `@stackskeptic` instead!"